# glEnableClientState deprecated

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

I want to use GL_POINT_SPRITE_ARB + VBO for my particle system rendering. 
I've done all preparations with point_sprites, but stuck at VBO.
It seems that glEnableClientState, is not working. I read that it is deprecated in modern openGL. So, what should i use instead?

Answer (score 21):

`glEnableClientState` is how you tell OpenGL that you're using a vertex array for a particular fixed-function attribute (`gl_Vertex`, `gl_Color`, etc). Those are all removed from core contexts. You should use [`glEnableVertexAttribArray`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glEnableVertexAttribArray) to enable a [generic vertex attribute](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Attribute), and you use [`glVertexAttribPointer`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glVertexAttribPointer) to [associate that attribute with a buffer object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Array_Object).